# How to convert a "YYYY:MM:DD" that xlrd reads as a float to a date in python

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, date, xlrd

If you have an excel with dates stored in a format "YYYY/MM/DD" there is no much problem, excel stores it as an integer and you can make it a date by using:

```
x = work_sheet.cell(1,4).value #in excel this cell is "2006/02/04"
dt = datetime.fromordinal(datetime(1900, 1, 1).toordinal() + int(x) - 2)
print(dt)
```

which will return

```
2006-02-04 00:00:00
```

However there is other dates in the excel stored in a different format "YYYY:MM:DD" if you try the same code in this cells with

```
dt = datetime.fromordinal(datetime(1900, 1, 1).toordinal() + int(x) - 2)
```

it will allways return

```
1900-03-23 00:00:00
```

and if you try

```
dt = datetime.fromordinal(datetime(1900, 1, 1).toordinal() + x - 2)
```

it says it expected a float and gives an error. So I used :

```
x = work_sheet.cell_value(rowx=1, colx=0) # in excel this cell is "2006:02:04"
print(xlrd.xldate_as_tuple(x, 1))
```

and the output was:

```
(1904, 3, 24, 14, 2, 4)
```

Is there a form to make it a normal date? I think is kind of making it like if it was a smaller time since 1900-03-23 00:00:00, and making it a lot of hours, but I don't really get it.

*EDIT WITH SOULTION*

Thanks for your help, this is the code that solves the problem!

```
def floatHourToTime(x):
    t1 = datetime(1904,1,1,0,0)
    too = xlrd.xldate_as_tuple(x, 1)
    t2 = datetime(too[0],too[1],too[2],too[3],too[4])
    too = t2-t1
    year = too.days*24 + int(too.seconds/3600)
    month  = int(too.seconds/60-int(too.seconds/3600)*60)
    day =   24*3600 *(x- (year/24)- (month/(24*60))  )
    return datetime(year,month, round(day) )
```

Comment: The date is being interpreted as a time which is a decimal portion of 1 (a day) or more than 1 day with time..

Comment: for the example it is giving me 83.58476851851852 , how is this a portion of a day? how to make it a normal date?

Comment: `2006:02:04` ==> 2006 hours, 2 minutes, 6 seconds or about 83,584... days.

Comment: `(1904, 3, 24, 14, 2, 4)`is when you add those 83,xx days to the `1904.01.01`  base date - see http://xlrd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dates.html - best thing to do would be to reformat your excel. xlrd will only give you the float value and you can not know if its a "real" time or a magled "date"...

Comment: @GabrielOctavioLozanoPinzón , you may share the answer in the Answer tab, to remove this question from 'unanswered' list. ( :